# "Am I doing it right"-type question for an existing question?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

### Scenario

**Existing question**: *How do I do xyz?*

**Existing answer 1**: *you do A*

**Existing answer 2**: *you can also do B*

**Existing answer 3**: *or you can do C*

---

### Question

- If I have a "Am I doing it right" question that pertains to the topic above and is not covered by any of the existing answers, I can't post it as **New answer 4**: *you can also do D*, as I am not 100% positive it is a correct solution
- I can't post it as question either as it would be marked as duplicate of the existing question above

How should I go about it?

Comment: What do you mean by *"type a question for an existing question?"* Submit a new answer? Create a new question? Can you elaborate (OK here in comments)?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I've just edited the question title and added quotes in the hope it's clearer. A longer title would be "How to deal with questions that ask _Am I doing it right_ and that provide a potential new answer to an existing question?"

Answer (score 3):

> - If I have a "Am I doing it right" question that pertains to the topic above and is not covered by any of the existing answers, I can't post it as **New answer 4**: you can also do D, as I am not 100% positive it is a correct solution.

If you just have a conjecture, that this could be another answer, then it's not ready for posting (we want to have quality and facts). You have to prove that your answer works (or need to have anecdotical reference) first.
In case you just want to do a shot in the dark and let someone else (e.g. the OP) prove it, you just take the risk, that your answer will be downvoted (and possibly deleted) for being incorrect.

If you have a very similar question, and don't know the solution D already, you should post a new question, and explain why the solutions you found for the existing question don't fit your needs.

If you already know that a new question would be marked as a duplicate of another one, and you know an alternative answer, add your answer to that original question rather than posting a new question and self answer it.
If you see a question you answered, and it's closed as duplicate, move your answer to the duplicate target. Preferably also delete your answer from the duplicated question if you can (i.e. the OP didn't mark it as accepted).

These are the correct and preferred solutions for the situaitons mentioned above. We want to have as much relevant information in one place as possible.

---

<sub>Note that a question that tends to have many possible solutions as an answer, it should probably be closed as too broad (needs more focus), or for lack of details.</sub>

Comment: What about questions that have different ways to go about it? Example: question _how do I backup xyz in Windows_ has mutliple answers such as _use backup program A_ or _use copy command_ or _use robocopy_ etc. - what if I have another potential solution which I don't want to post as answer as it has not been tested but a more experienced user can validate it? That is the jist of my original post.

Comment: @Dave I added that to my answer now.